# Why does object initialization throw `java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack`?

Tags: scala

Reproducible Example:

```scala
object Main extends App {
  val bar = new Bar(None)
  println(bar)
  val foo = Foo.newFoo
  println(foo)
}

trait Foo {
  type A <: Option[String]
}

class Bar[AA <: Option[String]](val a: AA) extends Foo {
  override type A = AA

  override def toString: String = s"Bar(${a})"
}

object Foo {
  def newFoo: Foo = new Bar(None)

  type FullA = Foo { type A = Some[String] }
  def safeGetA[U <: FullA](u: U): String = u match {
    case foo: Bar[_] => foo.a.get
  }
}
```

Result:

```
Bar(None)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack
Exception Details:
  Location:
    Foo$.safeGetA(LFoo;)Ljava/lang/String; @17: invokevirtual
  Reason:
    Type 'scala/runtime/Nothing$' (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to 'Bar'
  Current Frame:
    bci: @17
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'Foo$', 'Foo', top, 'Foo', 'scala/runtime/Nothing$' }
    stack: { 'scala/runtime/Nothing$' }
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: 2b4e 2dc1 0012 9900 1b2d c000 213a 0419
    0x0000010: 04b6 0025 c000 27b6 002b c000 2d4d a700
    0x0000020: 0fa7 0003 bb00 2f59 2db7 0032 bf2c b0  
  Stackmap Table:
    append_frame(@33,Top,Object[#53])
    same_frame(@36)
    full_frame(@45,{Object[#2],Object[#53],Object[#45],Object[#53],Object[#33]},{})

    at Main$.delayedEndpoint$Main$1(Main.scala:4)
    at Main$delayedInit$body.apply(Main.scala:1)
    at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:39)
    at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp$(Function0.scala:39)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:17)
    at scala.App.$anonfun$main$1(App.scala:76)
    at scala.App.$anonfun$main$1$adapted(App.scala:76)
    at scala.collection.IterableOnceOps.foreach(IterableOnce.scala:563)
    at scala.collection.IterableOnceOps.foreach$(IterableOnce.scala:561)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:919)
    at scala.App.main(App.scala:76)
    at scala.App.main$(App.scala:74)
    at Main$.main(Main.scala:1)
    at Main.main(Main.scala)
```

The exception is thrown when initializing object `Foo` -- in order for the exception to appear, the method `safeGetA` must be defined, but it need not be called or referenced. Note that construction of a `Bar` succeeds when its constructor is called directly; the exception is triggered on the first reference to the companion object `Foo`.

My question is not only "what is going on here" but "what syntax pattern is causing this" so that I can avoid it in the (more complicated) real software environment where this first cropped up. (In this simplified example, changing the wildcard match to a concrete

```
case foo: Bar[Some[String]] => foo.a.get
```

does not trigger the error, but leaving `String` existential

```
case foo: Bar[Some[_]] => foo.a.get
```

does. I have no idea what the relevant difference is.) In particular, what is the value of type `scala.runtime.Nothing$` which the runtime is trying to coerce to a `Bar`, and why is such a coercion being attempted?

There are a number of SO questions featuring similar errors, but none of those with accepted answers appear to reproduce the issue here.

Comment: What Scala version are you using? How/where do you run your code?

Comment: Reproduced on Scala 2.12.11 and 2.13.5, on multiple JREs (e.g. 1.8.0_191, 1.8.0_292, and OpenJDK 11.0.9.1+1-post-Debian-1deb10u2).

Comment: The code you provided doesn't compile. Correct it please.

Comment: Argh, went back and forth between the versions where `Bar` was a case class versus a vanilla class.

Comment: Another data point: any reference to `Foo` triggers the object initialization and the runtime error. Scala3 won't compile this code. Remove `: String` as the `safeGetA()` return type and Scala3 will compile and run. [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/Jw0k3gTDR86DAg4baJyB2Q)

Comment: Looks like a compiler bug. You should open an issue at https://github.com/scala/bug/issues

Comment: @jwvh Well, the question is then what is `safeGetA` return type after you removed `: String`. Isn't it `String`? Then why does removing `: String` make a difference? :) Possible bug in Dotty too. https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/issues